# Updating Configurable price in the database

Tags: php, configurable-product, database, simple-product

I need to update the Price for all configurable products in the database but I am not sure what table or column to use within my query.

I am almost there as I can enter the lowest priced simple product Price for all configurable products in a new table I created but what I need is to update the current price of the configurable products.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

include 'pathtocredentials.php';
$con = mysqli_connect  ($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

$configurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

foreach ($configurable as $_configurableproduct) {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());
    $id = $product->getId();
    $price = $product->getFinalprice();

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE some_table SET some_column=$price WHERE id=$id";

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to comment currently, however I can guide you:

Price is stored on the **catalog_product_entity_decimal** table linked to product ID (called entity_id)

So your query would now be

> mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value=$price WHERE entity_id=$id");

You might want to try and see if this works for you.

**Note**: Please take database backup before doing this.

Comment: I will try this soon thanks. I'm curious. Would it be "WHERE entity_id=$id" ?

Comment: That's right. Updated my answer.